# How to remove document from mongodb and update client?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an issue with below code i am deleting user and updating user List to the client , so when i call api to delete users it takes sometime to delete and my updated userList rendered data including deleted users. How to execute remove properly ?

controller.js

```
    export function destroy(req, res) {
        console.log(req.params.id);
        UserAccess.findOne({
            attuid: req.params.id
        }, function(err, user) {
            if (user) {
                user.remove();
            }
        });
    }
```

this will return userLIst

```
    export function index(req, res) {
        UserAccess.findAsync()
            .then(responseWithResult(res))
            .catch(handleError(res));
    }
```

index.js

```
router.get('/', controller.index);
router.delete('/:id', controller.destroy);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call remove() with a callback function and make then call for the usersList

```
export function destroy(req, res) {
            console.log(req.params.id);
            UserAccess.remove({attuid: req.params.id}, function(err,removed) {
                    if(!err && removed){
                       //call getUsersList function
                    }

            });
     }
```

Comment: How we can call  getUserList funtion that is `index`  in myabove code ?

Comment: if(!err && removed){
        index(req, res);
                    }

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UserAccess.findOne({attuid: req.params.id}).remove().exec();
```

`mongoose.model.findOne` returns a Query, which has a [remove function](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-remove).

Comment: How you differ your first answer with my code in question ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean instead of it, check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[`findOneAndRemove()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndRemove)** method as follows:

```
export function destroy(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.id);
    UserAccess.findOneAndRemove(
        { attuid: req.params.id },           
        function(err, user) {
            console.log(user);
        }
    );
}
```

The current implementation takes a while since the **[`remove()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.remove)** method is async and you haven't supplied a callback with the function.

The above signature for **[`findOneAndRemove()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndRemove)**

```
UserAccess.findOneAndRemove(conditions, callback) // executes
```

will execute immediately since a callback is passed, else a [`Query`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query-js) object is returned.

---

If you have a list of users to remove then the above method will no longer work since it only removes a single document matching the specified condition. You would need the **[`remove()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.remove)** function where the condition uses the `$in` operator to query the list, as in the following example:

```
export function destroy(req, res) {        
    UserAccess.remove(
        { "attuid": { "$in": userList } },           
        function(err, result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: how about if we have list of user to destroy ? would it still be good approach ?.

Comment: If you have a list then you need to use the `remove()` method as in the updated answer.

Comment: i was just asking about different scenarios we have option to select multiple user to delete and if there is only one user to delete `$in` will work in that case ?

Comment: It should work for a single user as follows `UserAccess.remove({ "attuid": { "$in": [req.params.id] } }, callback);`